# Issues with custom import of orders in Magento 2.4.6 (Adobe Commerce)

Tags: csv, magento, import, magento2, magento2.4

I am following the tutorial [Create a custom import entity](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/tutorials/backend/create-custom-import-entity/) . However, instead of importing learning courses as shown in the tutorial, I'm attempting to import orders.

To adapt the tutorial for orders, I made the following changes:

```
- const TABLE = 'learning_courses';
+ const TABLE = 'sales_order';
```

and

```
- protected $validColumnNames = [
        'entity_id',
        'name',
        'duration'
    ];

+ protected $validColumnNames = [
'entity_id',
'state',
'status',
'coupon_code',...];
```

After making these changes, I encountered an issue where the $bunch variable still holds the old CSV data, even when using a CSV file adapted to the sales_order attributes:
`$bunch = $this->_dataSourceModel->getNextBunch()`

i tried adding `$this->_dataSourceModel->cleanProcessedBunches();` before the while loop, this change successfully updates the data for the first iteration, but subsequently, the back office freezes.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try deleting the data in the importexport_importdata table.
The issue will be resolved.

Comment: thanks, I was able to solve it by using $bunch = $this->_dataSourceModel->getNextUniqueBunch(), Magento keeps track of the unsuccessful import files in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$bunch = $this->_dataSourceModel->getNextBunch()` you can use `getNextUniqueBunch($ids = null)`. This method will only retrieve the *next unique bunch of validated rows*. All you have to do is pass the ids of the validated rows to this method. You can get them by executing `getIds()` method on the import class.

It should look something like this: `$bunch = $this->_dataSourceModel->getNextUniqueBunch($this->getIds())`. In my case it solved the problem completely.